# Strip and format coordinate pairs

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have an array of coordinates `test` that I would like to turn into a string format

```
print(test)
[[[-122.45939656328747, 37.796690447896445], [-122.45859061899071, 37.785810199890264], [-122.44198816647757, 37.786535549757346], [-122.43578239539256, 37.789920515803715], [-122.42828711343275, 37.77444638530603]]]
```

the expected output is

```
 "-122.45939656328747, 37.796690447896445 | 122.45859061899071, 37.785810199890264 | -122.44198816647757, 37.786535549757346 | -122.43578239539256, 37.789920515803715 | 
-122.42828711343275, 37.77444638530603"
```

The following code only removes the outer brackets, how would one remove the inner brackets and place a pipe ("|") in between the coordinate pairs using python?

```
import re
print(str(test).strip('[]'))

test = re.sub('[[]]', '', test)
```

Comment: what does the outer brackets stands for in raw data?

Comment: the coordinate pairs are from geojson lines, so the outer brackets represent where one linestring ends and another begins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the outer brackets seem to be unimportant in your question, I remove it by `test[0]`, the following code should give what you want.

```
result = [str(coor).strip('[]') for coor in test[0]]
result = " | ".join(result)
```

Comment: I think I like the .strip better than my [1:-1], will mess things up less if `coord` is something unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you've got a list that contains one item, and that item is a list of lists. A bit odd but ok. First step would be to extract the list of lists, easy enough, just get index zero. Then what I would do is make each of those inner lists a string, (instead of casting the whole thing to string, as you did above) and use join on the big list, like so:

```
formatted = ' | '.join([str(pair) for pair in test[0]])
```

Edit: realized that the above answer will result in each pair having brackets around it, which I guess you don't want. Easily fixed by just dropping the first and last character:

```
formatted = ' | '.join([str(pair)[1:-1] for pair in test[0]])
```